# Search OneDrive folder (shared or owner) by unique ID

Tags: c#, onedrive, asp.net-core-6.0, microsoft-graph-api

We store all of our files in a OneDrive folder called "Company Files" on my account, however I am developing a ASP.Net Core MVC application that uses MS Graph API to read the OneDrive account. Users log in and the access token is used for authentication for MS Graph. I use the following request to search my own drive for certain files:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("select", "name,id,webUrl")
};

var search = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root
    .Search("document.docx")
    .Request( queryOptions )
    .GetAsync();
```

However if the user is not me this request will only search their own drive and not the drive I have shared with them. Is there a way to search a shared folder by some drive ID and not root? I also do not want the searching to be outside of the folder "Company Files" as I may put some personal files in this OneDrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the drive id you can use the endpoint

```
GET /v1.0/drives/{id}/...
```

SDK code:

```
var search = await graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].Root
    .Search("document.docx")
    .Request( queryOptions )
    .GetAsync();
```